# Issue in firing the server side event of rad context menu

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, rad-controls

Please check the below screen

[image]

When the user clicks the first dynamic menu , then the user clicks the context menu the server side event(item_click) is executed.As soon as the user clicks the user clicks the second dynamic menu and then again clicks the context menu first time the server side event (item click) is not executed.After selecting 3-4 times again the context menu hits the server event.

The dynamic menu are filling inside repeater.The code of radcontext menu is below in aspx page:-

the whole inner content changes with the click of every dynamic control menu.This is attached inside placeholder.

Please let me know why the server event of context menu stops firing once we go inside one dynamic control but the client event fires.

-Sulekha

Answer (score 0):

Probably you do not recreate something right. Make sure to create your dynamic controls in the Page_Init event and to provide the same IDs for them each time. If this is not done, server events tend to fail and even the ViewState may not load properly.